# Assigning `var location` in global scope redirects to non-existent file

Tags: javascript, window.location

I have an HTML file `test.html` where I have two variables both named `location`, one global and one local. But when I open it in browser it just says `Your file was not found`, and the address bar shows `file://Los%20Angeles` instead of `file://test.html` as expected. Why?

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var location = "Los Angeles"
function showLocation() {
    var location = "San Francisco"
    document.write(location)
}
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="showLocation()" value="Show Location"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'location' is a reserved keyword in javascript. Just change your variable name into something else.
For more info about reserved words: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

Comment: Also since you've declared a variable outside a scope (global variable) if your goal is to modify the value, all you have to do is to just call the variable inside your function and just assign a new value to it, no need to declare it again.

Comment: @jhek thanks. I was just trying to test the result of using the same name to declare a global var and a local var.

Comment: Thank you! I never thought about reserved keyword : )

Comment: This answer is still the wrong one: `location` is not a reserved word at all. Changing the variable name is the least safe and least future-proof approach, because it doesn’t avoid the fundamental issue. If a new standard introduces another clashing property name, you’d have to rename again, forever. Instead, using [JavaScript modules](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) is the safest and most future-proof approach, because modules have their own scope and their own lexical environment; no clashes are possible there.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the global `location` causes the browser to go to that URL. It’s not a reserved word<sup>1</sup> — it’s a property defined on the global object (`globalThis`, which is `window` in the Web).

In your example, you are setting the global `location` to `"Los Angeles"`, which causes the browser to navigate to that as if it was a relative URL.

Setting `var location = "San Francisco"` inside your function has no effect on the window object because the running execution context inside a function has its own variable environment, which is different from the one in global scope.

So you could do this:

```js
function showLocation() {
    var location = "San Francisco";
    
    document.write(location)
}
```

and it will work as expected. It will write the string `"San Francisco"` to the document.

If you are on a modern browser, you can see what’s going on by trying so set 'location' with 'let':

```js
let location = "los angeles";
```

Now you will get an error that says something like:

> `SyntaxError`: Can’t create duplicate variable that shadows a global property: '`location`'.

---

<sup>1</sup>: If you want to know what the reserved words are in JavaScript, take a look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#keywords).

Comment: The current best practice to avoid this issue is to use [JavaScript modules](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules), which have their own scope, and their own variable environment (or more precisely LexicalEnvironment). I’ve written [an answer](/a/51062916/4642212) to a related question that provides a complete list of variables that behave similarly. It’s not too easy to characterize these variables, but it’s basically non-configurable `Window.prototype` (and other) properties with setters.